# How to use hover selector to show an "uncle" element

Tags: css, css-selectors

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8582tg2/, I'm trying to use the hover selector to show a tooltip but can't get it to work.

```
<div id="typeahead-box">
    <div class="ic-tokens">
        <div class="ic-token">Hover over</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="tooltip">Should show</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make reference to the second level div so I can show the tooltip div?

Comment: You can't. The closest you could come would be a hover over the `ic-tokens` container, e.g. `.ic-tokens:hover + div > #tooltip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combinators `~` and `+` only work on sibling elements.

Therefore it wasn't working because `.ic-token` isn't a sibling element with that `div` element. Since you can't select parent element(s) in CSS, this is currently not possible.

The closest you can get is:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqp58xna/)

```
#typeahead-box:hover .ic-tokens + div #tooltip {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this is the correct answer. That it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

.ic-tokens:nth-child(2) { }

This would get the 2nd child of ic-tokens class. It's a stupid way to do it though. If I were you I'd use JS to do this.

Comment: That doesn't look good. You're right, I think I'm better off using JS